# Adding background image to Jekyll minima theme

Tags: yaml, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, minima

I am trying to include a background image to my Jekyll minima website that fills the whole window, similarly to the style here: https://orianna-zzo.github.io/AllinOne-html/

I have tried to implement the both the first half and the second half of the top answer here: [How to render background image in a page generated by Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157109/how-to-render-background-image-in-a-page-generated-by-jekyll), but the image doesn't insert for me even after significant time looking at Jekyll help pages trying to troubleshoot. I have tried many configurations of the image url and also tried to use local copies, eg.

```
.hero {
  background: url('about/pic.jpg');
  background: url('pic.jpg');
  background: url('./about/pic.jpg');
  background: url('./pic.jpg');
  background: url(about/pic.jpg);    etc.
}
```

where 'about' here is a directory within the main repo which contains the image file. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: try putting it in `/assets/images/pic.jpg`, see e.g. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/07-assets/

Comment: and perhaps for the urls to be processed, maybe you have to put a markdown-like frontmatter (two lines with just `---`) at the top of your css file...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - it doesn't look like it yet. To be completely clear, I've added
---
--- (on first and second line)
to the top of _sass/minima/_layout.scss, added 
/* Cover Image */
.hero {
  background: url('assets/images/pic.jpg');
}
to the end of the text linked in the post, and my url is defined in my _config.yml as 
`url: "https://me.github.io/"`. I made sure the new assets folder was pushed to Github.

Comment: My _layouts/home.html is:

`---
layout: default
---

<div class="home">
  {%- if page.title -%}
    <h1 class="page-heading">{{ page.title }}</h1>
  {%- endif -%}

<div class="hero">
  {{ page.hero_text }}
</div>

{{ content }}`

etc. as given in the linked post, sorry for the formatting

Comment: it's a bit hard to reproduce without the whole repo... if i were you, i'd try to get it running locally (on your own computer) first: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/testing-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll